# TypeError: _utils_errorhandler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I am making a ErrorHandler.js to handle error in my nextJs api, I previously used this in my node-express server. But when the API returns an error instead of showing me the error it returns me this - `TypeError: _utils_errorhandler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a constructor`
I have made a class known as Errorhandler here is the code for it :

../utils/errorHandler.js file:

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

Then I made a **middleware function** using this class and marked all my error init, here is the code:

../../middleware/error.js file:

```
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorhandler");

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";

  // Wrong Mongodb Id error
  if (err.name === "CastError") {
    const message = `Resource not found. Invalid: ${err.path}`;
    err = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
  }

  // Mongoose duplicate key error
  if (err.code === 11000) {
    const message = `Duplicate ${Object.keys(err.keyValue)} Entered`;
    err = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
  }

  // Wrong JWT error
  if (err.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
    const message = `Json Web Token is invalid, Try again `;
    err = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
  }

  // JWT EXPIRE error
  if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
    const message = `Json Web Token is Expired, Try again `;
    err = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
  }

  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    message: err.message,
  });
};
```

I tried changing it to ES6 module but it didn't worked for me. The API code is here :

```
import connectToMongo from "../../middleware/db";
const ErrorHandler = require("../../middleware/error");

const handler = (req, res, next) => {
  return next(new ErrorHandler("Test successful", 404));
};

export default connectToMongo(handler);
```

I am testing the ErrorHandler here so and it returns me the same error in all my API routes
It also returns next() is not a function some times.

The full Error is here :

```
error - (api)\pages\api\test.js (5:14) @ handler
TypeError: _utils_errorhandler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a constructor
  3 |
  4 | const handler = (req, res, next) => {
> 5 |   return next(new ErrorHandler("Test successful", 404));
    |              ^
  6 | };
  7 |
  8 | export default connectToMongo(handler);
```

Comment: Did you try importing the class `import { ErrorHandler }  from "../../middleware/error";`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you asking about a problem with your original code (which looks okay) or the change to ESM (which doesn't)? If the latter, you can't use `require` in an ESM module. I'm surprised you don't get a different error for it. To import something in ESM, you use `import` (as you did on the previous line), not `require`.

Comment: the ErrorHanlder in two files are imported from two different files.

Comment: I also notice that you've changed where you're trying to get it from. In the CommonJS code at the beginning, it's `../utils/errorhandler` (which seems like it would make sense). In the later code, it's `../../middleware/error`, which seems...odd.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I appreciate your tip; yes, you are right, English is not my first language, so learning about this cultural aspect for me is valuable and thank you for letting me now.

Comment: I add that ../utils/errorhandler is file where I have created Class, and ../../middleware/error is the function using that class ErrorHandler. Sorry my mistake I didn't mentioned file name let me fix it. Thank you for your responses

Comment: @RahulJujarey Thanks for your response, I tried your method but it didn't worked.
Currently the Error is - _utils_errorhandler__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a constructor

Comment: You have to import the `ErrorHandler` class from the `/utils/errorhandler` in your `pages/api/test.js` file, e.g. `import ErrorHandler from "../../utils/errorhandler";`.